# Proof for sequence $\frac{n^5}{3^n} \rightarrow 0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, limits-without-lhopital, epsilon-delta

I am improving my skill at formal sequence convergence proofs, I find them very tricky. I want to prove that:

$$\frac{n^5}{3^n} \rightarrow0$$

This should be read as "converges to zero", the question is, how large should $n$ be?

I would want a way to compare these two expressions I have trouble picking a big $n$ because I do not quite understand how to compare denominator and enumerator. Could someone drop a small hint so I can continue with my proof, I do not want to use any limit theorems.  What I want is that for $n>n_0$:

$$\left| \frac{n^5}{3^n} \right|< \epsilon$$

Comment: "converges for large $n$" has little meaning. The truth is that it converges.

Comment: Ratio Test leads to a nice proof.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test

Comment: "the question is, how large should n be?"  That depends on how close you want $\frac {n^5}{3^n}$ to be to $0$. If $n = 3$ then $\frac {n^5}{3^n} =9$.  Annd $9$ is close enough to $0$ if you are shooting an arrow at the side of a barn from a distance of three feet.

Comment: that made me laugh :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $n \geqslant 6$, by binomial theorem, 
$$
3^n = (1+2)^n = \cdots \geqslant ?
$$

Comment: $\sum_ {k=0} ^n \binom{n}{k} 2^k \geq... $

Comment: $ \geq \frac{2^6}{6!} n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)(n-4)(n-5)$

Answer (score 1):

You'd like $\dfrac{n^5}{3^n} < \epsilon$.

This is equivalent to $5 \log n - n \log 3 < \log \epsilon$.

Can you show that $5 \log n - n \log 3 \to -\infty$?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to show is that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an $N$ so large that $n > N$ implies $n^5/3^n < \varepsilon$. Alternatively you can use l'hopitals rule.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the ratio of two successive terms,

$$\frac{t_{n+1}}{t_n}=\frac13\left(1+\frac1n\right)^5.$$

When

$$1+\frac1n<\sqrt[5]3$$ i.e. $n>4$, it becomes less than one, and from there the sequence decreases to $0$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $e^y =3$ where  $y >1.$

Then $\dfrac{n^5}{e^{(yn)}} \lt (\dfrac{6!}{y^6})\cdot \dfrac{1}{n}.$